# insert point on every second char input

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have input user will insert his temperature for example

```
360 or 325 or 334
```

I want it automatically insert point on every second number like

```
36.0 or 32.5 or 33.4
```

i have tried like using this

```
string.replace(/(..?)/g, '$1.').slice(0,-1)
```

but it will ignore 0 as the part of input,
maybe someone knows of a better way?

Comment: What do you want from `12345 or 12345`?

Comment: would they literally enter `360 or 325 or 334` ... why would someone have a temperature that is one of 3 values? wouldn't a temperature be a single value?

Comment: @JaromandaX i want user put the value without putting a point so it less time and faster that way to record temperature, so when user type 360 it will show 36.0 or if 343 it will show 34.3 directly

Comment: ok, so then `(Number(string)/10).toFixed(1)` will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match 3 digits, with the first two in a capture group and the third in another capture group, and replace with `$1.$2` (the groups with a `.` between them):

```js
console.log(
  '360 or 325 or 334'.replace(
    /(\d{2})(\d)/g,
    '$1.$2'
   )
 );
```